# After page 7 of unanswered questions, there are questions with answers?

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

As soon as you hit page 8 (of 50 results per page) of unanswered questions and beyond,  all the questions have answers; is this a bug?

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions?page=8&sort=unanswered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions?page=8&sort=unanswered

That list shows all "questions that have no upvoted answers" (as the tooltip states). So this would seem to be correct. Whilst questions from page 8 onwards do indeed have answers, none of them have been upvoted!

To get just the list of questions that literally have no answers at all then the tabbed "Unanswered" link at the top of the page returns this:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/unanswered

Comment: I see, I must have missed the tooltip. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It is perhaps a bit confusing that both links are labelled the same "unanswered", but the information returned would seem to be correct . It's tricky thinking of another single word that would be appropriate.

Comment: Suppose the closest might be 'No Answer accepted' or similar.